# Is it possible to have handleRequest function in a Spring Controller along with annotations for parameters?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, controller, annotations

I just started working with spring and set up a simple spring project in NetBeans.  By default it doesn't seem to use annotations.

In one of my controllers I'd like to handle different clicks on the form.  I have looked at some solutions and it seems like adding a parameter check could work:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "someAction")
public ModelAndView doSomeAction() {
```

However it looks like all of the requests are going to:

```
public class SetupController implements Controller {
@Override
public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView handleRequest(
        HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {
```

Is there a way I can achieve the same effect without RequestMapping annotation?

Comment: Yikes, what version of Spring is this?  Haven't seen a straight implementation of that interface in forever :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seams that you mixed the old (implements Controller) style with the new one annotation based style.

You can't (or at least should not) mix them, at least not for one class.

If you use Spring 3.x then I strongly recommend to use the Annotation based style.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public class DemoController() {

   @RequestMapping(params="x");
   public ModelAndView doX() {
   }

   @RequestMapping(params="y");
   public ModelAndView doY() {
   }
}
```

To enable the Annotation Based style, you need at least this configuration settings:

```
<!-- Turns on support for mapping requests to Spring MVC @Controller methods 
  Also registers default Formatters and Validators for use across all
      @Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService" />
```

Comment: Got it. I believe you are correct.  Since my project was set up with the old style controllers is there a way to handle the requests based on parameters with the old style controllers?  I understand that there is probably a way to provide a controller for every possible URL but I'd prefer to consolidate the code to where one controller handles all of the parameters under "/whatever" and "/whatever?x" is handled in doX() while "/whatever?y" is handled in doY().  Thanks!

Comment: @mikebz: you can write one controller, that inspect the http parameter in an switch and invoke the correct method (doX, doY) for this parameter

Comment: I will do that but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  I guess the more elegant solution is the new annotations.